# How do I stop auto signing in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to type my password every time I open Chrome. How do I do that?

To be clear: I don't want to break the Chrome account and Google Services link. If I am logged in Chrome, I want to still be able to pass the authentication to Google services (e.g Gmail) automatically. But I want the first authentication in Chrome to be explicit forced every time.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that account authentication in Chrome is persisted with cookies, so if you just clear your cookies after using the browser, that effectively logs you out.